# Can I safely use evolution 3.12.4-0ubuntu1 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: evolution

Can I safely use evolution 3.12.4-0ubuntu1 in Ubuntu 14.04?  The current version (3.10.4) in the repository has a fatal flaw - creating new folders crashes Evolution.  This is apparently fixed in 3.12.4